# inaccurate result using pytesserract

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, pytesser

This [image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6BRn.png) [image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmyXl.png)

The problem is that the result is not accurate ,the result should be as follows

```
>>>>>>>>> "Prv:2.700 0p:2,70o Lo1:31.5&5 (mg: —5 Hi:2,71D val: 8.55"
```

Does anybody know how to optimize the image to achieve the best result ?

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

size = 279,18
im = Image.open("box6_line1.png")
box6_resized_line1 = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
box6_resized_line1.save("box6_resized_line1", "PNG")
box6_rs_line1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(box6_resized_line1, config='-psm 6')
print (box6_rs_line1)
size = 279,18
im = Image.open("box6_line2.png")
box6_resized_line2 = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
box6_resized_line2.save("box6_resized_line2", "PNG")
box6_rs_line2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(box6_resized_line2, config='-psm 6')
print(box6_rs_line2)
```

Comment: You're running into a problem that has existed for OCR engines for decades: similar characters are easily confused. How many samples did you train for each character?

Comment: i was try to resize the aspect ratio from that image, and have better result, but still, the problem is same as before, some time the result become unaccurate again